# Where is the Graduating Class in "Dazed and Confused"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dazed-and-confused

*Dazed and Confused* takes place on the last day of school. Pink, Kevin, Slater and the rest featured cast are either juniors or soon to-be-paddled 8th graders. There are some notable exceptions: Julie Simms, who serves as a love interest for Mitch, Wooderson, 'All right, all right, all right.', and the only mentioned senior, Fred Obannion.

So where are the other current seniors? Shouldn't we at least feel their presence on the last day of their high school career and at the moon tower party? Is there an absence mentioned somewhere in the movie? I can picture them maybe not attending school, but not partying as well? Are they on a senior trip? Tell me!

Answer (score 6):

It is not unusual for Seniors do be done with school earlier than the other classes.  In our area, depending on graduation schedules, they can be done over a week earlier. So their absence is explainable.

That being said, the graduating class was not important to the story, so adding characters of that age would serve no purpose.  O'Bannion was included because he got held back.

> Dawson: Did you hear that O'Bannion flunked?
>
> Pink: Yeah, what a dumbshit.

But the other seniors are gone, they have moved on, they are done with high school.   This is something that some of the characters in the film are bursting to do...

> Pink: All I'm saying is that if I ever start referring to these as the best years of my life - remind me to kill myself.
>
> Dawson: Well, all I'm saying is that I want to look back and say that I did I the best I could while I was stuck in this place. Had as much fun as I could while I was stuck in this place. Played as hard as I could while I was stuck in this place... Dogged as many girls as I could while I was stuck in this place.